# If Jobscience is built with Lightning components, why are documents corrupted?

Tags: lightning-experience

The Jobscience website claims they have been Lightning compatible since 2017, yet my boss still seems to have compatibility problems.  She is concerned that this app and others will not function properly when we are forced to switch to Lightning Experience this October.  In Jobscience, shared resumes arrive at the recipient garbled and illegible.  What am I not understanding about apps such as this which purport to be built with "Lightning Components"?

Comment: Hi Martial, welcome to SFSE. This question sounds like it is best directed to Jobscience support.

Comment: That was my first thought David Reed.  However, after looking into it,  Bullhorn/Jobscience was unable to define a solution other than to make sure all parties are using Chrome as a browser.  But that is not feasible, given that we have no control over what browser our clients use.